# Add 10.5 seconds with DateInterval

Tags: php

```
$Datetime = $Datetime->add(new DateInterval('PT'.$secondsToAdd.'S'));
$Datetime = $Datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

If $secondsToAdd is an integer everything works fine, but if it's equal to 0.5 or 10.5 it fires an error.
Can someone help me? How can I add 10.5 seconds?

Comment: `DateInterval` doesn't support microseconds yet

Answer (score 2):

Looking around the internet, it would seem that the native `DateInterval` is not currently able to handle fractions of a second. A [couple](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52519) of [bugs](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53831) have been accepted but have not yet been acted upon.

<strike>I found [this](http://joshp.me/dateinterval-milliseconds/) extension of the `DateInterval` class that claims to be able to handle it (untested but looks promising).</strike>

The solution linked above has the right idea, but it does not do the job. In order to make this work, one would need to overload all the methods of `DateInterval` to account for the additional capabilities of the class, and one would also need to extend `DateTime` in a similar way. I will leave the link in because it is not completely useless but it does not solve the problem completely.

I will try and add some more useful information when I have played around with it and come up with something workable.