# DateInterval: Unknown or bad format

Tags: php, datetime, fatal-error, dateinterval

I get several [dateTime](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#duration) informations through an API. It's format is like `P29DT48M56.941999S` for example. I would like to convert it with to a readable sting using [DateInterval::format](http://php.net/manual/de/dateinterval.format.php). My snippet looks like

```
$interval = new DateInterval('P29DT48M56.941999S');
echo $interval->format(' %d days, %I minutes');
```

Unfortunally, I get this error:

**PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateInterval::__construct(): Unknown or bad format (P29DT48M56.941999S)'**

What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: I suspect your fractional seconds is the problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817172/add-10-5-seconds-with-dateinterval

Comment: I see, so one has to remove the microseconds information before formatting. `preg_replace("'/.([0-9]{5,6})/'", "", "P29DT48M56.941999S")`  works fine!